# Foundation 6 Off Canvas Menu

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, zurb-foundation

I am trying to add an off canvas menu to my web, but I'm a beginner with foundation and i don't know how to use it.I have read the docs of Foundation Sites and i have looked for building blocks but i can't add off canvas.This is my HTML:

```
<div class="off-canvas-wrapper">
<div class="off-canvas-wrapper-inner" data-off-canvas-wrapper>
    <div class="off-canvas position-left" id="offCanvas" data-off-canvas>    </div>
    <div class="title-bar">
        <div class="title-bar-left">
            <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-open="offCanvas"></button>
            <span class="title-bar-title">Title</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="off-canvas-content" data-off-canvas-content></div>
</div>
```

I press the button for open off canvas but my menu doesn't appear.I have used this libraries

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/foundation.css"/>
<script src="style/foundation.js"></script>
<script src="style/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="style/css/app.css"></script>
<script src="style/bower_components/foundation-sites/js/foundation.core.js"></script>
<script src="style/bower_components/foundation-sites/js/foundation.dropdownMenu.js"></script>
<script src="style/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="style/bower_components/foundation-sites/js/foundation.util.keyboard.js"></script>
<script src="style/bower_components/foundation-sites/js/foundation.util.box.js"></script>
<script src="style/bower_components/foundation-sites/js/foundation.util.nest.js"></script>
<script src="style/bower_components/what-input/what-input.js"></script>
<script src="style/bower_components/foundation-sites/js/foundation.offcanvas.js"></script>
```

Thanks

Comment: can you create a fiddle please?

Answer (score 1):

Copy this:

```
  <div class="off-canvas-wrapper">
    <div class="off-canvas-wrapper-inner" data-off-canvas-wrapper>
    <div class="off-canvas position-left" id="offCanvas" data-off-canvas>MY OFF CANVAS</div>
    <div class="off-canvas-content" data-off-canvas-content> <button type="button" class="button" data-toggle="offCanvas">Open Menu</button></div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

I hope it helps! In the div with the "Open Menu"-Button you put the hole page...

Answer (score 0):

some steps to help you up:

1. It seems like you've included all of your elements yourself. this is a bad practice and i suggest you'd include all of foundation's JS in one file (like they hand you when you download a new install of foundation in 
   [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/download.html/).
2. please make sure you go after Foundation's structure. from the docs, the structure for an Off-Canvas element is:

Full link to the docs is [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/off-canvas.html)

```
<body>
  <div class="off-canvas-wrapper">
    <div class="off-canvas-wrapper-inner" data-off-canvas-wrapper>
      <div class="off-canvas position-left" id="offCanvas" data-off-canvas>

    <!-- Close button -->
    <button class="close-button" aria-label="Close menu" type="button" data-close>
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>

    <!-- Menu -->
    <ul class="vertical menu">
      <li><a href="#">Foundation</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dot</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">ZURB</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Com</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Slash</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sites</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>

      <div class="off-canvas-content" data-off-canvas-content>
         <!-- Page content -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```